# Can't find a mini connector (2x5, 0.05")

Tags: pcb, connector, cables

I am looking for a connector as shown in the image below. I am able to find the connector itself [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/5327?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA84CvBhCaARIsAMkAvkJhtro_grFFGYJgno9R_bye77RDB4u0DppRktMtPw2zFH9ti23X9JYaAntlEALw_wcB). But, I need cable connected to it as well. Can someone help me find this connector with cables connected to it?

[image]

Comment: `Can someone help me?` is not a question about electronics

Comment: That connector looks like it is inended to be soldered into a through-hole PC board.  However, you could solder wires to the pins.  What is the spacing between pins?

Comment: The spacing is 0.05". I have a sensor which has a male socket for this, I was wondering if I could find a female socket with cable attached so I can connect it to my PCB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually one uses male headers with an IDC cable such as this: 
https://www.adafruit.com/product/1675 
or say [Samtec SFSD](https://www.samtec.com/products/sfsd) or related parts.

If the header in question has alignment features, shrouding, etc., perhaps a better mate exists.  Usually plain header is used for board-to-board purposes only (in production), and perhaps with a socket such as this for programming (during development and testing); as can be seen in the above link, they're a popular choice for JTAG/SWD connectors